# divide a vector to many smaller vectors based on a condition

Tags: matlab

I have two vectors (length = 172992), `A` has some double data and `B` has only 0,1,2,3 and 4 as values. I need to move on both vectors and check the value of `B`. if `B` is not zero, create a new vector and put in it all `A`'s values  from that index till `B` return became zero and so on .. then create a matrix with all the newly created vectors. Any Help??

```
%Example:
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0  7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0  4 4 4 4 4 4  ];
B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0  3 3 3 3 3 3  ];
%The output:
Mat = [ 1 2 3 4 5 6;  7 7 7 7 7 7 ;4 4 4 4 4 4 ];
```

Comment: Your matrix `Mat` is impossible because the number of elements in the rows differs.

Comment: sorry there was a missing 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Non-Rectangular

Since Matlab cannot handle non-rectangular matrices (as in your example), you will have to fall back to cell arrays to store each output vector.
You can filter the elements of `A` using a [logical index](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1) and [`arrayfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html?refresh=true):

```
>> A = [1 2 3 5 6 0 0 0 0  7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0  4 4 4 4 4 4  ];
>> B = [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0  3 3 3 3 3 3  ];
>> sol = arrayfun(@(c) A(B==c),1:max(B),'UniformOutput',false)

sol = 
    [1x5 double]    [1x6 double]    [1x6 double]
```

You can then put the individual vectors into their own variables like this

```
[m1,m2,m3] = sol{:};
```

### Rectangular

For rectangular data (i.e., adding in a `4` into the first grouping of `A`) you can create the matrix much more easily (still using logical indexing):

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0  7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0  4 4 4 4 4 4  ];
>> B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0  3 3 3 3 3 3  ];
>> reshape(A(B~=0),nnz(B)/max(B),max(B))'

ans =
     1     2     3     4     5     6
     7     7     7     7     7     7
     4     4     4     4     4     4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Troy, Can we make four matrices each one holds the values of one number ( mat1,mat2,mat3 and mat4)?

Comment: by the way .. it is a rectangular matrix .. why the first one is 5X1 not 6X1?

Comment: It looks like your example code is missing a `4` in the first grouping.  Is the output always rectangular? ... I also added code to extract each element into its own vector.

Comment: yes it is rectangular .. sorry about the missing four .. The actual array is much bigger than the example. so I need to check all the vectors of one and but them in a matrix and the same for 2,3, and 4. Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it works fine. but how can I make the matrix for only the one values?

Comment: By construction, the `arrayfun` version does this by index.  The one-values are in `sol{1}`, the two values `sol{2}`, and so on.  The line `[m1,m2,m3] = sol{:};` create three separate vector associated with the values of `B`.

Comment: It do that, but m1 is a vector as it put all the values after each other and I need it to be a matrix where each vector is separated.

Comment: To be blunt, this makes no sense: "I need it to be a matrix where each vector is separated".  You can have variables that hold the vector of values associated with a certain value of `B` (there is no matrix to be formed), or you can have a single variable hold all elements of `A` associated with non-zero values of `B` in a matrix where each row or column corresponds to the value of `B`.  These are the two options.

Comment: I got your point, but I mean like in this example:
A = [1 2 3 4 5 6 0 0 0 0  7 7 7 7 7 7 0 0 0 0  4 4 4 4 4 4  ];
B = [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0  2 2 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0  1 1 1 1 1 1  ];
I need mat1 = [1 2 3 4 5 6; 4 4 4 4 4 4]; mat2 = [ 7 7 7 7 7 7 ]; and mat3 = []; mat4 = [];

Comment: What rule did you use to make those matrices?  Why are the `A` values from when `B` is `1` or `3` in a separate matrix from when `B` is `2`?

Comment: mat1 should have all the values of A which has the same indexes of the values of B = 1 so thats why mat1 has 1 2 3 4 5 6 as B is equal to 1 and again 4 4 4 4 4 4 as B began 1 again. as same for mat2 but for B =2 and so on